# CURL ERROR: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8

Tags: json, bash, curl, https, sh

I'm doing a bash script, when working out such an error ... I can't figure out what the problem is. I'm not good at scripting yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=LOGIN

password=123PASSWD

note_link=$(curl -s 'https://cryptgeon.nicco.io' \
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --data-urlencode "data=$data" \
    --data "has_manual_pass=false&duration_hours=0&dont_ask=false&data_type=T&notify_email=&notify_ref=" \
    | jq -r --arg arg $password '.note_link + "#" + $arg')

echo "note URL is $note_link"
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl`'s `-s` option is silencing the errors as well, but you want to see the errors in this case to be able to understand what is going wrong, so use `-sS` instead.

Also, jq can only parse json. If the input is not json, it will fail with the error you get. You should first try to parse the output with jq, and if it fails, display it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

data=LOGIN

password=123PASSWD

curl_output=$(curl -sS 'https://cryptgeon.nicco.io' \
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    --data-urlencode "data=$data" \
    --data "has_manual_pass=false&duration_hours=0&dont_ask=false&data_type=T&notify_email=&notify_ref=")
if note_link=$(jq -r --arg pass "$password" '.note_link + "#" + $pass' <<<"$curl_output" 2>/dev/null); then
  echo "note URL is $note_link"
else
  printf >&2 %s\\n "Could not parse the curl output:" "$curl_output"
fi
```